# Which package type will be preferred for ISV?

Tags: managed-package, appexchange, isv, unlocked-package, second-generation-packaging

I am planning to list my app in exchange, As ISV what is the preferred type for Listing.

when I try to add my 2gp package for security review it does not link my dependent package.

should I have to pay for each package security review ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pay an Annual fee.

You don’t have to go through a security review every time you release a new version of your solution. Just follow the same submission process in this unit, and it is automatically reapproved.

But Salesforce Product Security team can ask for your solution to be reviewed at any time, even after it’s been approved. Typically, AppExchange solutions are reviewed for security once a year.

Reference Link: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/v/modules/isv_security_review/isv_security_review_submit

https://partners.salesforce.com/s/education/appinnovators/Security_Review#z

Comment: my question is different, does 2gp supported in listing ?
from below link it says it's not yet available.

https://sfdc-db-gmail.github.io/unlocked-packages/faq-unlocked-pkgs.html#isv-packaging